# Html Combo box change key in index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Normally, in combo box, we key in letter b or c from key board, list will be moved to b or c in list. However, now my data list is as below:

```
1023 - Back to office
1982 - From home to office
1234 - Office to home
```

Is this possible to skip *1982 -* and move to *From* when I type *F*.

I don't know which event is going to use in this case.

Hope you guys understand it.

Regards.

Comment: are you looking for only first char match or string of chars entered by user?

Comment: Actually I'm looking for first char. tks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your data list is always formatted like this ("1982 - From home to office"). Then you can just split your data and look for the first char.

Comment: Hi, in this case, do we use keydown event and split the string? If it is, what next after that? How can we move the text to that select? Could you show me more hints? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can have an event then split and trim the string. Look for the char and if you find one then change the value of your select tag.